# Simple Cipher with std:out_of_range issue (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm totally new to programming and heard that C++ or the Assembly Language is a good startning point for someone that want to understand what happens under the hood. I want to follow this follow through even though some of you might have other suggestions. I've been an active student for a week now and for my second challange my teacher asked us to write a cypher. Nothing fancy, but something that scrambled and unscrambled the string written by the user. So far I've tried to scramble them for starters since I deduce that if I'll solve that problem, the unscramling will be achieved through a similar process. I know there's plenty of snippets of code out there already, but I'm really intressted and want to learn through the trial and error method, based on my own assumptions.

I would appriciate it greatly if someone could point out why I get the message: "Terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string latSorted {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ,."};
string latUnstorted {"-_qazwsxedcrfvtgbyhnujmikolp"};

int main() {

cout << "\n -----------------------------------------------" << endl;
cout << " Enter some text: ";
string usrText;

string* p_usrText; // Pointer Initialization
cin >> usrText; // User enter text
p_usrText = &usrText; // Memory allocation gets assigned to the pointer variable

cout << " You've entered " << *p_usrText << endl << endl;

for (size_t i=0; i < latSorted.length(); i++)
{
    char searchChar = latSorted.at(i);
    char cryptChar = latUnstorted.at(i);
    for(size_t j=0; j < usrText.length(); j++)
    {
        if(usrText.at(j) == searchChar)
        {
            *p_usrText = usrText.replace(usrText.begin(), usrText.end(), searchChar, cryptChar); // Memory allocation is still within range due to the pointer. Should not say "out of range".
        }
    }
}
cout << ' ' << usrText << endl;
cout << endl;
return 0;
}
```

Thx//Alle

Comment: Why are you using a pointer to a `std::string` at all?

Comment: What you're looking for - beyond what you may get here - is _how to run a program in a debugger_.  That will be of huge benefit to you.

Comment: The pointers confused me too. For starters I thought I would need them but then I recieved the out_of_range error which mad me think that I need a pointer. I know see that isn't the case. Thx @alter igel

Comment: Thx @DrewDormann. I'm at point 0.000001 in a journey a million points long. A couple of lessons in debugging will come in handy, I'm sure. But as of now I'm probably too stupid to make any use of it. I'll keep that in mind though. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `latSorted` and `latUnstorted` are different lengths.

`char cryptChar = latUnstorted.at(i);`

Would result in the exception for the last value of i.

Comment: Yepp. Thank you soo much @meat. That fixed the error and now I have more as you surely suspect. I'm going to make a run for it but I would be greatfull if you could hang around aid me in the future if you can. Thank you again

Comment: @Alle don't forget to hit that checkmark to mark this answer as "accepted", so people know that you're not still looking for help here.